# rewrite file to subdomain

Tags: .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, subdomain

We used this rules

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ http://news.mydomain.cop/news.php?n=%1 [L,R=301]
```

for redirect

- `http://mydomain.com/news.php?n=100`

  to
- `http://news.mydomain.com/news.php?n=100`

but we need

- `http://mydomain.com/news.php?n=100`

  and
- `http://news.mydomain.com/news.php?n=100`

redirect 301 to

- `http://news.mydomain.com/100.html`

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(news\.)?mydomain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^news\.php$ http://news.mydomain.com/%1.html? [L,R=301]
```

This will make it so if someone types: `http://mydomain.com/news.php?n=100` or `http://news.mydomain.com/news.php?n=100` in their browser's URL address bar, they'll get redirected to `http://news.mydomain.com/100.html`, thus changing the URL in the address bar.

Comment: It's not worked !!  

old link http://news.mydomain.com/news.php?n=100  



and new link http://news.mydomain.com/100.html  


redirected to home page !!

Comment: @MohamedAhmed There was a typo in the domain name, .com was .cop

Comment: @ Jon Lin we knew and we modified code but same results,it's redirected to home page !!

Comment: @MohamedAhmed As you can see, [it works perfectly fine for me](http://i.stack.imgur.com/ZWwIl.png). There's the htaccess file (using the above rules) and a request being sent as `http://news.mydomain.com/news.php?n=100` and `http://mydomain.com/news.php?n=100`, both redirect to `http://news.mydomain.com/100.html`. This is exactly what you asked for, if you've got nothing sitting at `100.html` then that's something completely unrelated.

Comment: @ Jon Lin you are right, it's redirected and this appears at address bar in browser but content related to home page !!!
 also we tried with this


RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^domain\.net [NC] 
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^n=(.+)$
RewriteRule ^(.+)\.php$ http://$1.domain.net/demo/%1.html? [R=301] 

but same result redirect but content of main page !!!

still need help

Comment: still need help or any new suggestion

Comment: @MohamedAhmed No new suggestions, I told you the problem is elsewhere, the rules to do what you asked work perfectly for me, you need to debug this issue. There's no way I'm going to.

Comment: why do think your code not work for us?? if there is new code please give us it